# "Absolute value" tag

Tags: discussion, tag-proposal

We have [a number of questions on absolute values of random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22absolute+value%22+distribution+is%3Aq), e.g.

- [Expected value of the absolute standardized t distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/466428/1352) (this is what motivates this question)
- [What is the expectation of the absolute value of the Skellam distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/279220/1352)

Somewhat to my surprise, we don't seem to have an [absolute-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-value) tag that would allow searching for questions that carry this tag and, say, the [t-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/t-distribution) or [skellam](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skellam) one.

In fact, the sheer desirability of such a tag seems so obvious to me that I am sure I am missing something. So: what argues against such a tag? Or should we create it and start (judiciously) retagging?

Comment: I don't think anyone explicitly did not create the tag because of some argument against it. No one has simply created it yet. If you see the need, go ahead.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I have explicitly created the tag  (and engaged in some exuberant new tag-application) precisely to give folks the opportunity to explicitly unmake the tag. :)

Answer (score 3):

I see value in this suggestion, and have created the [absolute-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-value) tag, and invite you to improve upon both my quick and dirty précis and the [info page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/absolute-value/info).

I also invite anyone critical of the tag to motivate its reform or removal in a separate answer.